# Loop over tensor dimension 0 (NoneType) with second tensor values

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a tensor `a`, I'd like to loop over the rows and index values based on another tensor `l`. i.e. `l` suggests the length of the vector I need.

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

a = tf.constant(np.random.rand(3,4)) # shape=(3,4)
a.eval()

Out:
array([[0.35879311, 0.35347166, 0.31525201, 0.24089784],
       [0.47296348, 0.96773956, 0.61336239, 0.6093023 ],
       [0.42492552, 0.2556728 , 0.86135674, 0.86679779]])

l = tf.constant(np.array([3,2,4])) # shape=(3,)
l.eval()

Out:
array([3, 2, 4])
```

Expected output:

```
[array([0.35879311, 0.35347166, 0.31525201]),
 array([0.47296348, 0.96773956]),
 array([0.42492552, 0.2556728 , 0.86135674, 0.86679779])]
```

The tricky part is the fact that `a` could have `None` as first dimension since it's what is usually defined as batch size through placeholder.

I can not just use mask and condition as below since I need to compute the variance of each row individually.

```
condition = tf.sequence_mask(l, tf.reduce_max(l))
a_true = tf.boolean_mask(a, condition)
a_true

Out:
array([0.35879311, 0.35347166, 0.31525201, 0.47296348, 0.96773956,
   0.42492552, 0.2556728 , 0.86135674, 0.86679779])
```

I also tried to use `tf.map_fn` but can't get it to work.

```
elems = (a, l)
tf.map_fn(lambda x: x[0][:x[1]], elems)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TensorArray` object can store tensors of different shapes. However, it is still not that simple. Take a look at this example that does what you want using `tf.while_loop()` with `tf.TensorArray` and `tf.slice()` function:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_data = np.array([[0.35879311, 0.35347166, 0.31525201, 0.24089784],
                       [0.47296348, 0.96773956, 0.61336239, 0.6093023 ],
                       [0.42492552, 0.2556728 , 0.86135674, 0.86679779]])
batch_idx = np.array([3, 2, 4]).reshape(-1, 1)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 4))
idx = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None, 1))

n_items = tf.shape(x)[0]
init_ary = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,
                          size=n_items,
                          infer_shape=False)
def _first_n(i, ta):
    ta = ta.write(i, tf.slice(input_=x[i],
                              begin=tf.convert_to_tensor([0], tf.int32),
                              size=idx[i]))
    return i+1, ta

_, first_n = tf.while_loop(lambda i, ta: i < n_items,
                           _first_n,
                           [0, init_ary])
first_n = [first_n.read(i)                      # <-- extracts the tensors
           for i in range(batch_data.shape[0])] #     that you're looking for

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(first_n, feed_dict={x:batch_data, idx:batch_idx})
    print(res)
    # [array([0.3587931 , 0.35347167, 0.315252  ], dtype=float32),
    #  array([0.47296348, 0.9677396 ], dtype=float32),
    #  array([0.4249255 , 0.2556728 , 0.86135674, 0.8667978 ], dtype=float32)]
```

**Note**

- We still had to use `batch_size` to extract elements one by one from `first_n` `TensorArray` using `read()` method. We can't use any other method that returns `Tensor` because we have rows of different sizes (except `TensorArray.concat` method but it will return all elements stacked in one dimension).
- If `TensorArray` will have less elements than index you pass to `TensorArray.read(index)` you will get `InvalidArgumentError`.
- You can't use `tf.map_fn` because it returns a tensor that must have all elements of the same shape.

The task is simpler if you only need to compute variances of the first `n` elements of each row (without actually gather elements of different sizes together). In this case we could directly compute variance of sliced tensor, put it to `TensorArray` and then stack it to tensor:

```py
n_items = tf.shape(x)[0]
init_ary = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,
                          size=n_items,
                          infer_shape=False)
def _variances(i, ta, begin=tf.convert_to_tensor([0], tf.int32)):
    mean, varian = tf.nn.moments(
        tf.slice(input_=x[i], begin=begin, size=idx[i]),
        axes=[0]) # <-- compute variance
    ta = ta.write(i, varian) # <-- write variance of each row to `TensorArray`
    return i+1, ta


_, variances = tf.while_loop(lambda i, ta: i < n_items,
                             _variances,
                             [ 0, init_ary])
variances = variances.stack() # <-- read from `TensorArray` to `Tensor`
with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(variances, feed_dict={x:batch_data, idx:batch_idx})
    print(res) # [0.0003761  0.06120085 0.07217039]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my opinion, looping over the `batch_size` will most likely to raise an `IndexError` on the last batch of the data, since the last batch usually have less rows than the predefined `batch_size`

Comment: If you only need variances, read the second part that I just appended. It computes variances of sliced tensors.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Consider accepting my answer then.